# As an undergraduate, how risky is it to aim for academia?

Tags: graduate-admissions, career-path, computer-science, undergraduate

I have just finished my first year at University, and after a slight tweak to my major (two very similar degrees) I'm ready to start my second year of computer science in September.

At this point, is it reasonable for me to plan to get into the world of academia? I ask is that I've heard getting into academia is very competitive, and I don't want to end up spending all my energy focusing on something with very low acceptance rates, like a first year bio major declaring that they will get into med school. If getting into academia is very difficult and competitive, I should probably start making back-up plans.

I've also heard that my interest area (quantum computing) is getting a decent amount of funding, but I'm not sure if that will make it any easier to get into. I plan to get into research ASAP, but unfortunately I've heard from a professor that they aren't interested in anyone who hasn't finished at least three years. I've been doing self-study about quantum computing so that maybe I can get some research in this area between second and third year.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: There is a great deal of overlap between industry and academia in many branches of CS, so if you want a safer route, you may aim for these. Even if you don't, the skills you pick up in CS are very transferable to industry, so you will still have routes open.